# Prove by induction that $W_n = F_{2n+2}$

Tags: proof-writing, induction, recursion, fibonacci-numbers

My problem relies on an earlier recursive definition that we solved in class:

$W_n = 3W_{n-1}- W_{n-2}$ if $n \ge 2, W_0=1$, and $W_1=3.$

It also recalls the Fibonacci recursive definition of $F_n = F_{n-1} + F_{n-2}$ if $n \ge 3, F_1\ge 1$, and $F_2 \ge 1$.

The problem asks me to prove by induction that $W_n\ge F_{2n+2}$ $\forall n \ge 0$.

For the base case, I checked $W_2 = 3W_1 - W_0 = 3\times3 - 1 = 8 = F_6$, which works out.

I'm not sure about what the induction step should be in this case. I know that I have to get to $W_{n+1} \ge F_{2(n+1)+2}$.

I'm thinking maybe I set up $W_{n+1} = 3W_n - W_{n-1}$ and try to translate the right into Fibonacci numbers. I haven't been able to find any induction problems that deal with the relationship between two difference recursive equations like this.

Thanks!

Comment: Your thinking is okay and working out gives a new problem: prove that $F_{2n+4}=3F_{2n+2}-F_{2n}$. Give it a try (and for convenience define $F_0=0$). If you succeed in this then you are ready.

Comment: Thanks drhab! I worked this out to $F_{2n+4} = 3(F_{2n+1} + F_{2n})-F_{2n}$ and from there eventually got to $F_{2n+4} = (F_{2n+3} + F_{2n+2})$.

Answer (score 1):

We have
$F_n = a \alpha^n + b \beta^n$, for some $a,b \in \mathbb R$, and $\alpha,\beta$ the roots of $X^2-X-1$. (Their precise value is not really important here, but see [Binet's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression).)

Then $F_{2n}=a (\alpha^2)^n + b (\beta^2)^n$. Now, $\alpha^2,\beta^2$ are the roots of $X^2-3X+1$ because $\alpha^2+\beta^2=(\alpha+\beta)^2-2\alpha\beta=1+2=3$ and  $\alpha^2\beta^2=(\alpha\beta)^2=1$.

Therefore, $G_n=F_{2n}$ satisfies the recurrence $G_n = 3G_{n-1}- G_{n-2}$, the same recurrence as your $W_n$. Since $W_0=G_1$ and $W_1=G_2$, we have $W_n=G_{n+1}=F_{2n+2}$ for all $n$.