# Pattern with $\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\-1&3\end{bmatrix}^k$. How can I prove what corner element will be?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, soft-question, integers, fibonacci-numbers

The matrix

$$B= \begin{bmatrix}0&1\\-1&3\end{bmatrix}$$

Is inspired by [this matrix which generates the Fibonacci sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4117809/213607).

Upon calculating a few powers of $B$, I noticed that $({B^k})_{2,2}$ seems to be ${F_{2(k+1)}} - {F_{2k}}$ but I lack an idea of how to prove it.

What would be a fruitful approach to do it?

Comment: You may try an induction argument or diagonalise the matrix.

Comment: Diagonalize and compare to Binet's formula for Fibonacci.

Answer (score 4):

I think a good idea to start is with the characteristic equation of $B$ which is
$$
\lambda(\lambda-3)+1=0\iff \lambda^2=3\lambda-1\implies B^2=3B+1.
$$
It is reasonable to write that
$$
B^k=a_kB+b_k,
$$hence
$$
B^{k+1}=BB^k=a_kB^2+b_kB=(3a_k+b_k)B+a_k=a_{k+1}B+b_{k+1},
$$
which yields
$$
{\\a_{k+1}=3a_k+b_k
\\b_{k+1}=a_k,
}
$$
hence
$$
{
a_{k+1}=3a_k+a_{k-1}
\\
b_k=a_{k-1}.
}
$$
From here, a bit of substitution and mathematical calculation would yield the final result.

Answer (score 3):

**Empirically:**

Let us have a look at a few successive powers:

$$\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-1&3\end{pmatrix}$$
$$\begin{pmatrix}-1&3\\-3&8\end{pmatrix}$$
$$\begin{pmatrix}-3&8\\-8&21\end{pmatrix}$$
$$\begin{pmatrix}-8&21\\-21&55\end{pmatrix}$$
$$\begin{pmatrix}-21&55\\-55&144\end{pmatrix}$$

We see that the elements are each time shifted north-west and a new corner element appears, which is $(-1,3)$ times the right column. Hence the recurrence

$$c_{n+2}=3c_{n+1}-c_n,$$ starting with $1,3$.

Comment: Nice observation. So what remains is to try and tie this recursion to the recursion of the Fibonacci sequence, I presume.

Answer (score 3):

*Hint:* Prove by induction that
$$
\begin{bmatrix}\hphantom-0&1\\-1&3\end{bmatrix}^k
=
\begin{bmatrix}-F_{2k-2} & F_{2k} \\ -F_{2k} & F_{2k+2} \end{bmatrix}
$$
You'll need that $F_{n+2} = 3F_n-F_{n-2}$. For a proof, adapt [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3466957/589). See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2951426/prove-by-induction-that-w-n-f-2n2).

Comment: Following the data provided by Yves Daoust

Comment: In general, $F_{n+k}=L_{k}F_{n}-(-1)^{k}F_{n-k}$, where $L_k$ is the $k$th [Lucas number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_number)